# Why do I always get 1 for df when running adonis function (permanova)?

Tags: vegan, linux-disk-free

I run adonis on community data and environmental matrix (that contains a factor of two levels and 6 continuous variables) using Bray-Curtis and I always take 1 df but this is not the case. Probably there is a bug here.

See also the example in adonis

```
data(dune) 
data(dune.env)  
str(dune.env)  
adonis(dune ~ Management*A1, data=dune.env, permutations=99)
```

Although A1 is a numeric variable the result provides 1 df.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear what the issue is; A1 is a continuous variable and hence does only use 1 degree of freedom, just as it would in a linear regression model.

Answer (score 0):

In the model:

```
> adonis(dune ~ Management*A1, data=dune.env, permutations=99)

Call:
adonis(formula = dune ~ Management * A1, data = dune.env, permutations = 99) 

Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 99

Terms added sequentially (first to last)

              Df SumsOfSqs MeanSqs F.Model      R2 Pr(>F)   
Management     3    1.4686 0.48953  3.2629 0.34161   0.01 **
A1             1    0.4409 0.44089  2.9387 0.10256   0.02 * 
Management:A1  3    0.5892 0.19639  1.3090 0.13705   0.21   
Residuals     12    1.8004 0.15003         0.41878          
Total         19    4.2990                 1.00000          
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The *main* effect of `A1` uses a single degree of freedom because it is a continuous variable. The interaction between `Management` and `A1` uses 3 additional degree's of freedom as there is one additional "effect" of `A1` per level of `Management`.

This is all expected and there is certainly no bug illustrated in `adonis()` from this model.

Importantly, you must insure that factor variables are coded as factors otherwise, for example if the categories are coded as integers, then R will still interpret those variables as continuous/numeric. It will only interpret them as factors if coerced to the `"factor"` class. Check the output of `str(df)`, where `df` is **your** data frame containing the predictor variables (covariates; the things on the right-hand side of `~`), and insure that each factor variable is of the appropriate class. For example, the `dune.env` data are:

```
> str(dune.env)  
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ A1        : num  2.8 3.5 4.3 4.2 6.3 4.3 2.8 4.2 3.7 3.3 ...
 $ Moisture  : Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "1"<"2"<"4"<"5": 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 4 3 2 ...
 $ Management: Factor w/ 4 levels "BF","HF","NM",..: 4 1 4 4 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ Use       : Ord.factor w/ 3 levels "Hayfield"<"Haypastu"<..: 2 2 2 2 1 2 3 3 1 1 ...
 $ Manure    : Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "0"<"1"<"2"<"3"<..: 5 3 5 5 3 3 4 4 2 2 ...
```

which indicates that `Management` is a factor, `A1` is numeric (it is the thickness of the A1 soil horizon), and the remaining variables are **ordered** factors (but still factors; they work correctly in R's omdel formula infrastructure).

Comment: Thanks, I haven't realized so far that continuous variables in permanova use single df.

Comment: Continuous variable in any (linear) model uses single df. Check `lm` & `glm`.